Getting OAuth code challenge on loopback server
I’m implementing the authorization code grant flow for my CLI app with PKCE
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-8.1
I started a loop back server from the CLI to wait for the authorization code from my auth server:
$ mytool login
$ please visit: mysitethattalkstomyauthserver.com?local_port=65200
$ … awaiting auth code …

It’s working fine but I’ve a question about the code verifier. I want to have my user just click the above url and have my website handle the initial request for auth code. BUT I need the code verifier hash in the initial request. I should generate that from the client cli tool and not my website.
So do I need to stick that hash in the original url I have the user click?
$ please visit site.com?port=65200&challenge=<hash>

Right now I have an implementation that just has the site call
localhost:65200/code_challenge

And the cli provides the code hash it generated. Is that secure though? To have this extra step of calling my local loop back server to get the code challenge?
Purpose here was to keep the url for user to click on as simple and readable as possible

Hm i've come across PAR which might be what I actually want. Looking into it

A CLI client must run its own HTTP server and operate like this.

Create a code verifier and store it in memory
Run a local HTTP server, eg at http:/127.0.0.1:3000
Open the system browser at the authorization request URL, including the code challenge
Receive an authorization response URL in the local HTTP server containing the authorization code
Send the authorization code grant request, with the code verifier, to the authorization server's token endpoint

You should not try to involve a web server since your CLI will not be able to receive the response URL. The local HTTP server is spun up in your CLI's technology atack, eg Node.js can use its built in HTTP server.
Note also (from your comment) that you cannot use PAR for a CLI client, which is a public client that cannot safely supply the client credential that PAR requires.

Thanks Gary, your recommendation sounds great and I can do that. I was mostly curious about the step:

Open the system browser at the authorization request URL, including the code challenge.

I thought it would be nice to provide a more readable url: site.com/login?local_port=1234 instead of site.com/login?code_challenge=<>&client_id=<>&scope=<>&redirect_uri=<>&code_challenge_method=<>
I was looking at concourse's fly login for an example

Sure - the CLI's external interface can be something easy like mytool login with everything else happening internally . Unless you have special requirements there should be no need for other parameters or to click a link. Instead, the next thing the user should see is a login form in the system browser.

Fair enough! I'll go with "Press enter to open browser" or something as I've seen in github. Thanks for the input
